# Bash script to start venv in VSCode from Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, visual-studio-code

I'm following a tutorial from a Windows guy creating a bash script to start Virtualenvironment in VScode.

I try to do the same thing under Linux Ubuntu 20.10.
I use last version of VSCode (1.53.2)

I hope it's not needed to buy windows PC to automatize with bash scripts !!

Here is my script and the file is open_project.sh :

```
 #!/bin/bash
    cd /home/fablab/Desktop/dev/mycoffee/venv
    source bin/activate && code .
```

I expect this result :

[image: VScode venv ok]

But I get this behavior :

[image: VScode venv nok]

I tried suggestions from thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script:

[image: Suggestion1]

Any idea ?
Maybe works in windows because the terminal (cmd ?) is linked with vscode terminal somehow ?

Edit :

It works is I launch the bash from VSCode terminal using :

```
source open_project.sh
```

But I would like it to work from desktop by double clicking the open_project.sh ...

Edit :

I tried a different way but still not satisfying :

added in the settings.json :

"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true

but still no activated venv on start (the loading of the seetings happens after the launch therefore I still need to manually relaunch the terminal to get venv activated ...

Still stuck, nobody ?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`

Comment: returns nothing, in ubuntu terminal or in vscode terminal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Thanks, I managed to activate venv inside the terminal through the bash script using this question, but never managed to do it inside VScode ... what do I do wrong ?

Comment: When you say `code .`, you are opening, it will open visual studio code with current directory as project folder, but you never instructed visual studio code about virtual environment.

Comment: It seems to work in the windows tutorial I am following, but I take any suggestion to make it work in the linux OS ...

Comment: What is the tutorial link ?

Comment: [https://www.udemy.com/course/python-from-zero-to-hero/learn/lecture/21939632#notes](https://www.udemy.com/course/python-from-zero-to-hero/learn/lecture/21939632#notes)   Not the best tutorial on earth but I am 60% trough ...